# Prove by limit definition $\lim _{x\to \infty }\left(\frac{-7x^2+9x}{4x^2+8}\right)=\frac{-7}{4}$

Tags: calculus, limits, functions

Prove by limit definition

$$\lim _{x\to \infty }\left(\frac{-7x^2+9x}{4x^2+8}\right)=\frac{-7}{4}$$

let $\epsilon > 0$   need to find $M$ such that for every $x>M \implies |f(x) - L|<\epsilon$

$\left|\frac{-7x^2+9x}{4x^2+8}+\frac{7}{4}\right| = \frac{9x+14}{4\left(x^2+2\right)} \le \frac{23x}{4x^2}=\frac{23}{4x} < \epsilon $

so I choose $M=\frac{23}{4\epsilon}$

My question is that I assumed that $x>0$ do I need to check when $x\le0$ or this is enough since  $x \to \infty $ ? and does this prove the limit ?

thanks

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy $\left|\frac{-7x^2+9x}{4x^2+8}+\frac{7}{4}\right|=\left|\frac{4\left(-7x^2+9x\right)+7\left(4x^2+8\right)}{4\left(4x^2+8\right)}\right|=\left|\frac{-28x^2+36x+28x^2+56}{4\left(4x^2+8\right)}\right|=\left|\frac{36x+56}{4\left(4x^2+8\right)}\right|=\left|\frac{9x+14}{\left(4x^2+8\right)}\right|$

Comment: Sorry, I was wrong.

Comment: if is written the limit at $x\to\infty$, so it means you have to count limits at $x\to+\infty$ and $x\to-\infty$.

Comment: @thing You are wrong… $x\to\infty$ means $x \to +\infty$

Comment: No, you don't need to check for $x \le 0$. What you have done proves the limit

Comment: @Gono, this is not a fact. If they write $x\to\infty$ in an improper integral or in the sum of a series, then they understand how $x\to+\infty$. And in the limit they usually write clearly, if it is not clear from the context which particular infinity

Comment: @thing actually it is a fact… please give at least one source for your claim

Comment: @Gono, In fact, there are many sources: Fichengolts, Zorich, Kudryavtsev. Here is a link to russian wikipedia (becousr i'm from Russia): https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB_%D1%84%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%BA%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B8#%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB_%D0%BD%D0%B0_%D0%B1%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%87%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8_%D0%BF%D0%BE_%D0%9A%D0%BE%D1%88%D0%B8. But I admit that in English-speaking countries the definitions are somewhat different.

Comment: @thing Thank you for the links. Wasn't aware of this (and I'm not from an english speaking country)… really seems to be a russian thing.

Answer (score 1):

Look for example at pp. 105, Calculus (Third Edition) from Spivak. The definition of $\lim_{x\to\infty} f(x)=L$ is that for every $\varepsilon>0$ there is a number $N$ such that, for all $x$, if $x>N$, then $|f(x)-L|<\varepsilon$. According to this, what you have done proves the limit, but I think that in your attempt to solve the problem it was necessary to assume $x>1$. Nevertheless this is not a problem because you can take $M=\max\{1, \frac{23}{4\varepsilon}\}$ to ensure that the bounds you took are ok.